# UIButton inside MKPinAnnotationView with image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, mkpinannotationview

i need to do `MKPinAnnotationView` with `UIButton` to the left side with a image like this:
[image]

i try to write this code but it's not work:

```
 let navBtn = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    navBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "TakeMe.png"), forState: .Selected)
    navBtn.tag = artwork.id
    navBtn.addTarget(self, action: "wazeNav:" , forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
    pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = navBtn
```

plz help me how i can do this?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No just don't see the button

Comment: Are you calling this in viewForAnnoation?

Comment: I do not think so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the code below

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    let annotationView = AttractionAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Attraction")

    let button : UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.InfoDark)

    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "funcRightAcessoryButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true

    let image = UIImage(named: "left_icon")
    let buttonLeft : UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    buttonLeft.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    buttonLeft.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
    buttonLeft.addTarget(self, action: "funcLeftAcessoryButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = buttonLeft

    return annotationView
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Workkkkkkk tanks you are the king!